# Overriding CSS inheritance in nested lists using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

The HTML for the navigation:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li id="navpart1"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li id="navpart2"><a href="destinations.html">Destinations</a>
            <ul>
                <li id="navpart3"><a href="#">London</a></li>
                <li id="navpart4"><a href="#">Rome</a></li>
                <li id="navpart5"><a href="#">Paris</a></li>
                <li id="navpart6"><a href="#">Venice</a></li>
                <li id="navpart7"><a href="#">Edinburgh</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        <li id="navpart8"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li id="navpart9"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I'm using the following jquery to add special CSS styling to the navigation for the current page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var mybodyid = $('body').attr('id');
        var mynavid = '#nav' + mybodyid;
        $(mynavid).attr('id','iamhere');
        $('ul ul').hide();
        $('#iamhere').parents().show();
        $('#iamhere').children().show();
    });
```

Special CSS styling for current page:

```
#iamhere a {
color: #ff0000; 
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

The jquery works but the nested lists are inheriting the special CSS as well (see image.)  In that image, I'm on the "Destinations" page so I want the "Destinations" nav link to be red while all of the other links maintain the link styling I've already set up in my CSS doc.

[Example of the issue with nested lists inheriting CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GLYq.png)

I tried adding CSS for the nested list items using their individual IDs with no luck:

```
#navpart3, #navpart4, #navpart5, #navpart6, #navpart7 {
color: #061AFF;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

I also tried adding jquery to change the color for children of #iamhere but that didn't work either:

```
$('#iamhere').children.css({'color': '#061AFF', 'text-decoration': 'none'});
    });
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: What element is `#iamhere`? It's not in your HTML sample

Comment: `#iamhere > a` restrict to direct childs

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan OP assigns the ID `iamhere` to the actual active element based on the id on the body check the JS

Comment: Ah yes, thanks @DaniP. I'd advise against changing id attributes dynamically, OP. They are intended to be static. Add a class on the relevant element instead

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I tried adding CSS for the nested list items using their individual
>   IDs with no luck

You need to target the `a` elements to override your page-specific CSS. Like this:

```
#navpart3 a,
#navpart4 a,
#navpart5 a,
#navpart6 a,
#navpart7 a {
  color: #061AFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Jon Uleis, I cannot believe what an idiot I am.  I knew there was a simple solution.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @Michelle No problem! Not sure why someone downvoted me - was just correcting a typo in the original attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Use `children('a')` to select all `a` tags inside the selector

```
$('#iamhere').children('a').css({'color': '#061AFF', 'text-decoration': 'none'});
```

Note: `Children()` is faster than `find()` as it search only its first level elements

### Pure CSS

To change in css itself use immediate child selector `>`

`#iamhere > a {`